# How to check if lldb can attach to binary?

Tags: c++, macos, lldb

I'm trying to attach lldb to a binary that is designed to be built for Linux. I'm editing a `CMakeLists.txt` file but I'm not sure if the flags I need (`-glldb -g3`) are being passed to the binary.

How can I introspect a running binary to check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way is to see if there's line-table information for one of the files in your project.  lldb has a command for this:

```
(lldb) image dump line-table  MySource.c
```

If you see a bunch of output mapping addresses to source lines, then there's debug information for at least that source file.  Otherwise not.